# Download image in "Download" folder

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have image in my app. When I am trying to download the image on my pc in the `Downloads folder`,but it is creating a **new folder** inside the Downloads folder, and saving my image there.

Why is this method creating a new folder instead of just downloading the file to the Downloads folder?

```
    public async void DownLoadImage()
    {
        var url = SelectedAsset?.VumarkImage?.AbsoluteUrl;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        {
            return;
        }

        var source = new Uri(url);

        StorageFile destinationFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(SelectedAsset.VumarkImage.OriginalName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
        await download.StartAsync();
        _toastService.Show("Vumark successfully downloaded to Downloads folder");
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `SelectedAsset.VumarkImage.OriginalName`?

Comment: It is the my image name .

Comment: I didn't ask what it represents. I asked what the value is.

Comment: Value it is the my file name. Or I do not understand how working the CreateFileAsync method.

Comment: You're wasting my time. Tell me the value of the property. I'm not asking for a description of it.  I'm asking for the actual value.

Comment: If I am writing instead SelectedAsset.VumarkImage.Original Name "FileName", my file is downloaded with the name "FileNAme" and the file type will be null. It all what I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  It doesn't appear to be documented; I [opened an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/260).

The API will create a specific subfolder for the calling app to put files/folders in created with the `DownloadsFolder` API.

To save a file directly to the Downloads folder, you'd have to get the user to choose that location using the [FileSavePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker) or get them to choose a 'default folder' with the [FolderPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker) and use that, just remember to [save a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders) to it for the future.